# Python: else ValueError: (Specifically ValueError In This Case)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, try-except

I have a question which is unrelated to my code. I'm just curious. Why is it that I (I don't know about you) can only use a ValueError with a try and except loop? for example:

```
print("What is 1 + 1?")
while(True):
    try:
        UserInput = int(input(("Your answer here:"))
        if(UserInput == 2):
            print("Congratulations you are correct!")
            break
        else:
            print("That is incorrect. Try again!")
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number. Try again!")
```

This works perfectly fine (or at least it should) but, why (if not) would this next piece of code not work.

```
print("What is 1 + 1?")
while(True):
    UserInput = int(input("Your answer here:"))
    if(UserInput == 2):
        print("Congratulations you are correct!")
        break
    elif(UserInput != 2):
        print("That is incorrect. Try again!")
    else(ValueError):
        print("That is not a number. Try again!")
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9
    else(ValueError):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know it is because ValueError only works (I think) with try and except loops but, why can't it not work in the above scenario? I assume they would give the same results but, I don't know everything. Maybe one of you amazingly smart people can tell me my that wont work or an alternative. Thank you for trying to clarify this to me :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try` and `except` are a form of control flow. Essentially, it means `try` to run this code, `except` if an exception occurs (such as `ValueError`) do something else.

`if` and `else` are another form of control flow. Together, they mean `if` a condition is true, do something; `else`, do something else.

An exception occurring is not a condition, and thus it would not make sense to use `else` with an exception like `ValueError`. Instead, you want to use the `try`/`except` block.

Answer (score 3):

The SyntaxError in the second example comes from the fact, that `else` needs no condition. The first example is totally ok.

Still better, keep the try-block as short as possible:

```
print("What is 1 + 1?")
while True:
    try:
        UserInput = int(input(("Your answer here:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number. Try again!")
    else:
        if UserInput == 2:
            print("Congratulations you are correct!")
            break
        else:
            print("That is incorrect. Try again!")
```

Comment: I think, last else is redundant.

Comment: So else can't have ValueError in it. Do you think that it would be easier the second way or not?

Comment: @Jacobian: no it isn't

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist: you cannot catch an exception with a `else`-clause.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist What do you mean by "easier"? You can't use `ValueError` with `else`, so it doesn't really make sense to ask if it would be easier considering it's not legal.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist `else` clause cannot have any statement between it and the `:` because it is the catch all `else:` case, you are thinking of `elif` which can have a conditional but the conditional would have to be "there was an error raised" which is what the `except` block was designed for.

Comment: So, what is the sense of the very last else, if the code breaks if UserInput == 2 and never reaches else part?

Comment: @RushyPanchal I was implying if it was legal would it be easier or would it make more sense.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist Neither – it would not make more sense, because an exception is not a condition. Also it's still not clear what you mean by easier, because they're essentially the same amount of work in terms of actually using either...

Comment: @RushyPanchal Okay. Thank you for helping justify this. I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

To `else`, no condition is necessary nor permitted. And also, you need to use `raise` for what you want

```
print("What is 1 + 1?")
while True:
    UserInput = int(input("Your answer here:"))
    if UserInput == 2:
        print("Congratulations you are correct!")
        break
    elif UserInput != 2:
        print("That is incorrect. Try again!")
    else:
        raise ValueError("That is not a number. Try again!")
```